# I can't get a bigcommerce store to scroll down via Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to do is get a bigcommerce store to automatically scroll down based upon a value.

The following does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").scrollTop = 500;
});
</script>
```

Nor does:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.scrollTop = 500;
</script>
```

Comment: take a look, how to use `scrollTop()` http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, "slow");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1363/)

Comment: nothing works, it's like the bigcommerce store has the scrollbar on complete lockdown